# K-nn to predict the class of the data using Euclidean distance in R

Tags: r, knn, euclidean-distance

I would like to apply k-nn on a learning set to predict the class of the data using the Euclidean distance.

I am finding some difficulties with implementing this method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the `knn()` function in `class` package. It is using the Euclidean Distance.

You can check its documentation for more detail:

https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/class/html/knn.html